# vertical and horizontal scales on raster

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have a raster image which is a log. What I like to be able to do is to extract the X any Y points from the raster. That are in two sets of units

[image]

The ideal outcome would be an output of an x and y 
[image]

Generally I am using Arc Gis . Does anyone know if there is possible here, or in another software on the standard package. My work does not allow many add ins to be readily downloaded

Comment: Are you already viewing this image in ArcMap?  What is your currnet environment like?  It may be helpful to know what version of ArcGIS you are using.

Comment: Hi there , no I do not have this in Arc map , I think I am on version 10 . I just took this picture and Annoted it in Power point as an example of what I would like to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in ArcMap.  It's a little hacky but you should be able to get the results you're looking for.  The concept of what you'll be doing is referencing the image to a cartesian coordinate system and then identifying points on it as if it were a map and those points were coordinates.

1. First, split the images into separate files.
2. Next, for each image create a text file that designates coordinates for the extent of the values in the scale for that image.  You'll need the first line to be "x,y".  It should look something like this (with numbers of course):

   `x,y
   min_x,min_y
   min_x,max_y
   max_x,max_y
   max_x,min_y`
3. Now, open ArcMap, and use the ArcCatalog window to find one of the text files.  Right-click on the text file and choose Create Feature Class > From XY Table...
4. In the dialog, choose a coordinate system.  This doesn't actually matter very much, as long as it's a projected coordinate system.  Search for UTM and pick your lucky number.
5. Specify an output feature class, doesn't really matter where, and once it's created, add it to the *empty* data frame.  *Make sure the data frame has the same coordinate system as the feature class*.
6. Zoom to the feature class, you should see a perfect rectangle.
7. Drop in the corresponding image, and use the georeferencing toolbar to match min, max coordinates on the image with the points you just made.  Tip: once you've added the image to the data frame, you may need to use Georeferencing > Fit to Display to get the image to show up.
8. Once you have matched the control points and Updated Georeferencing, use the identify tool to find coordinates on the image.  Make sure you are viewing Map Units as coordinates.  Judging from the x y scales on your image, it will appear widened, but hopefully it'll be legible enough to be useful...

Like I said: hacky, but it should work.  There may be better solutions, but this is what I can offer...  A very very similar approach could be taken in QGIS, I just don't know the specifics.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am sure there is a plug in within Quantum that brings this functionality think I used a long time ago , but can t remember. Thanks for this though